# httr authentication with twitteR

Tags: r, twitter, httr

I’ve just updated to the current github version of twitteR and am having some difficulties with httr authentication. I start by running the following:

```
library(twitteR)

consumer_key <- "---------------------"
consumer_secret <- "------------------------------------------"
access_token <- "-------------------------------------------------"
access_secret <- "-------------------------------------------"

setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_secret,
                    credentials_file = "twitauth.RData")
```

So far so good. Then in a new R session with twitteR loaded I run `load_twitter_oauth("twitauth.RData")`. This does not appear to work because I get the following error when trying to do anything that requires me to be authenticated, e.g.:

```
getCurRateLimitInfo()
[1] "object 'access_token' not found"
Error in twInterfaceObj$doAPICall("application/rate_limit_status", params = params,  : 
  Error: object 'access_token' not found
```

If instead of starting a new R session I try `getCurRateLimitInfo()` immediately after `setup_twitter_oauth` I get a different error:

```
getCurRateLimitInfo()
[1] "missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"
Error in twInterfaceObj$doAPICall("application/rate_limit_status", params = params,  : 
  Error: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Am I missing some step in the authentication process here? I get the same problem on my work PC and my personal Mac, both using R version 3.0.2.

Comment: Did you report this as an issue to the author: https://github.com/geoffjentry/twitteR/issues or the mailing list as specified on the READ.me of the github version: http://lists.hexdump.org/listinfo.cgi/twitter-users-hexdump.org?

Comment: I asked on the mailing list but got no response. Thought I'd ask here before reporting an issue in case the problem is with my code (likely) rather than the package itself. Based on other threads on the mailing list others seem to have been able to authenticate with no trouble.

Comment: Did you make sure the line `load_twitter_oauth("twitauth.RData")` works and your data is actually loaded?

Comment: I should have mentioned that no, it doesn't actually load my data (but doesn't throw an error either). So that is part of the problem, or one of two problems, but in the second case above all of my data are still in my workspace and still no luck.

Comment: This question looks outdated. Neither `load_twitter_oauth` nor setup's `credentials_file` argument exist in v1.1.8